# TeamCity MSTest and TestList?

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

In order to automate unit tests on *TeamCity* I had to create a test list in my `vsmdi` configuration file indicating that every test is part of a list I called `CompleteCoverage`. I dislike this a lot because in order to auto-run new tests I'll have to remember to include them on this list.

Is there some way to run every test in the solution using *TeamCity* and *MSBuild* (other than explicitly referencing the path to the output test assembly)?

Should I just drop *MSTest* and go for *NUnit*?

Comment: what is the issue with just referencing your test assembly if you want to run all tests?

Comment: the fact that depending on the configuration I have to specify different hardcoded locations `bin\Debug`, etc

Comment: `depending on the configuration` <-- ie Release vs Debug builds? If Yes, shouldnt these be separate builds (configuration) in teamcity?

Comment: The locations shouldn't need to be hardcoded if you use the Configuration property (ie. "Path\To\Project\bin\$(Configuration)\TestAssemblyName.dll").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using NUnit instead of MSTest, but this should work for you, too:

I've named all my test assemblies to include .NUnit in their name, e.g. Basic.NUnit.dll. In the build step performing the tests, I've declared **/*.NUnit.dll as the assemblies to run. To make sure that they are run in the right location, I've added **/obj/**/*.NUnit.dll to the exclude list. Together with test categories to in- or exclude, I've got perfect control over which tests to run on a purely declarative level without to name the individual tests.